# AWS ECS on EC2 - Set system date to a specific value

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ecs

Each night a job is invoked which checks whether it is first of a month. During our testing, we can't wait for days and hence want to change the system date to a first of the month so that job gets invoked and processes all transactions logged into database so far.

We are using AWS ECS on EC2. Containers largely run Java (Spring Boot) but other containers run NodeJS and Spring batch jobs (short lived tasks). Now I want to be able to set all containers to use a specific date (main requirement; and may be time too and that means that launch with some specific time and then run their clocks as normal clocks). The long running tasks are auto-scaled (min 3 and max 10).

How can this be achieved?

**Additional information**
The database is in UTC and all Java containers have time zone set to 'America/New_York'.
Other option thought was to override Java System.currentTimeMillis() through Aspect oriented programming (AOP) but the AOP code needs to invoked from some place. It was thought to do it through API but there are 2 issues, a) Unable not make AOP code to work yet & b) How to call API on each container when it starts?
EC2 instances run using Red Hat Enterprise Linux.

Comment: Have you tried setting the system clock in EC2 user data?

Comment: I tried on an EC2 instance (i.e. not on an EC2 instance used by ECS) but the command to set date fails since EC2 instance uses NTP and does not allow date to be modified. Now theoretically it is may be possible to disable NTP but not sure if customer would allow it.

Comment: Well surely you can do that in your own testing env?  You only need to disable ntp in production where you won't need to change the clock anyway.

Comment: Customer is very strict about modifying the AWS env in anyway. However, I can try. Can you share how to disable NTP on AWS EC2 instance?

Comment: I've not been following redhat so I'm afraid I can't show you the commands. But it must be running as a service so googling "disable ntp redhat" should get you there.